# NGINX resolver directive placement and inheretance

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

**My nginx.conf file contains only 1 server block.**

I've recently read a few guides and began to use the following directives in my nginx server block context.

**Specifically** `resolver` and `resolver_timeout`.

```
# Using ipv4 to listen on port 80

listen            80 default_server;

# Using ipv6 to listen on port 80

listen            [::]:80 default_server;

# Sets names of a virtual server

server_name       mysite.com www.mysite.com;

# Sets the root directory for requests

root              /usr/share/nginx/html;

# Configures name servers used to resolve names of upstream servers into addresses
# The IP addresses for Google Public DNS are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
# By default, nginx caches answers using the TTL value of a response.
# An optional valid parameter allows overriding it.

resolver          8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;

# Sets a timeout for name resolution

resolver_timeout  30s;
```

I have some questions that may appear naive but it's because I want to fully understand it.

**Question 1** - The DNS hosting provider for my domain contains an A Record for mysite.com that points to my static IP address with a TTL of 1H. Does that mean that I have to synchronize resolver with this value?

**Question 2** - Google's Public DNS seems like the way to go given their Globally massive infrastructure. Is it ok to just use the resolver directives in the `http` context one level up from server or placing it in the server block is best practice?

**Question 3** - If I'm using `php-fpm`, are the resolver directives ideally to be placed in the `fastcgi_pass` location block or can they remain in the server block and everything will work because of cascading?

```
# PHP scripts location block
location ~ \.php$ {

  # Security Setting #9 -> Use try_files to check if php script being passed 
  # is a file that actually exists.
  try_files       $uri =404;

  # Sets the address of a FastCGI server.
  # 
  # The address can be specified as a unix socket file, a domain name or IP address,
  # and a port.
  # 
  # In linux, we pass the PHP scripts to the PHP FastCGI Process Manager listening on 
  # a unix socket file.
  fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;

  # Sets a file name that will be appended after a URI that ends with a slash, in the value
  # of the $fastcgi_script_name variable.
  fastcgi_index   index.php;

  # You can use NGINX to "sanitize" the input to the application by setting the
  # HTTP_PROXY fastcgi_param to an empty string. This removes the parameter completely
  # from the FastCGI Process Manager request.
  fastcgi_param   HTTP_PROXY "";

  # Requires the server to use the root  directive
  # Requires the server to use the index directive
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;

  # Includes another file, or files matching the specified mask, into configuration.
  # Included files should consist of syntactically correct directives and blocks.

  # Includes adittional paramaters from fastcgi_params file.
  include         fastcgi_params;

} # END location block
```

Comment: What are you trying to resolve? Your `fastcgi_pass` directive uses a UNIX socket, which does not require access to DNS.

Comment: Ok. So if the `fastcgi_pass` directive is a domain and/or a port, its underlying IP address may change. Using the `resolver` directive allows you to keep it up to date. Now, I was under the impression that placing the `resolver` directives in the `server` block while using domains under the `server_name` directive would force nginx to always use google's public DNS `8.8.8.8` & `8.8.4.4` to resolve the IP address of mysite.com --- Is this correct?

Comment: According to [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_pass), the `fastcgi_pass` parameter needs to be specified with a variable in order for Nginx to use a `resolver`.

Comment: `resolver` directives seem worthless unless you are using upstream groups for load balancing.